Раскрытие списков в GridControl от devexpress
На форме Winforms располагается GridControl от devexpress подключенный к бд Firebird. В нем находятся списки. Мне надо сделать так чтобы по нажатию кнопки все списки раскрывались, а при повторном нажатии снова закрывались


Вот же документация - ExpandAllGroups(), CollapseAllGroups().
